# Why do I get automatic input in my interactive container application

Tags: c++, docker

I have a super simple cpp program that reads with `std::getline(std::cin, ...)` and `std::cin >> myint` and prints to `cout`. When I containerize that application and run it with `ENTRYPOINT` the application is getting input from somewhere to `STDIN`so it just runs to completion and my container stops. If I put my `getline` and `cout` in a `while(1)` loop that application just runs and runs, printing the same inputs to the logs over and over.

If I run the container interactively and start the same application I can interact with the application without problems.

What I would like to happen is that my application is started and when I later `docker attach` to the container so that I can manually interact with it. Is that possible somehow?

Comment: I would try to redirect the standard input to a socket (Unix domain). That way, you could just telnet of netcat to that socket to later interact with the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was very simple.

If not running with `-i`, `stdin` is not attached and as soon as I read something I get `EOF`. So the program just runs through and quits.

The answer is to run with the container with `-tid`, that is, keep `stdin` open, allocate pseudo-TTY and detach. That way the application is kept open and I can attach to the container at a later time and interact with it.